# Exporting a very large MySQL table to a .CSV using a SELECT statement?

Tags: export, mysql, export-to-csv

I've got a MySQL table with ~1B rows. I need to export a single column from every row into a CSV.

1. I've tried the following but the query uses all the memory on the local machine where I'm exporting the query and the `mysql` process gets killed.

   `mysql -uuser -ppass -h host.com --database=dbname -e "select column_name FROM table_name" > column_name_export.csv`
2. I can't use a `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` because the MySQL instance is running in Amazon RDS and I don't have access to the server.

Is there a MySQL utility to export this in batches, or do I need to write a script to select over ranges of ids?

Comment: How many records can the MySQL instance handle without choking when exporting to a CSV file?

Comment: Either you split the records into a number of range sets, or find something useful for your inquiry would do.

Comment: The local server where I'm creating the export is what runs out of memory. Perhaps the MySQL server will run out of memory also, but it has a lot more memory than my local machine.

Comment: What's the OS on your local machine? Also have you tried `mysql -Bnq ...` yet? Turns off some interactive stuff that isn't needed.

Comment: --quick (or -q) is the trick @miken32

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is using [Server-side cursors](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html#pymysql.cursors.SSCursor).

But in my case even the server ran out of memory (for very large tables), so I opted for splitting the file into multiple batches, ordered by any id.

Comment: just add --quick option to mysql CLI, that does exactly this